# Django - order ManyToManyField within a queryset result

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Simplified Models:

```
Class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    launch_date = models.DateField(blank=True)

Class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="collections", blank=True)
```

Say I want to return a Collection query but I want products returned with this queryset to be ordered by `launch_date`, how would I do this?

Just adding `order_by` on products launch dates to the query does not work as that just orders the collections, but doesn't actually order the products within the collections
`Collections.objects.order_by('products__launch_date').all()`

Comment: Do you mean the products returned when accessing the ManyToManyField on each Collection in the queryset or do you want to order the Collection queryset itself by the related launch_date? Can you show an example of what you have tried and what your desired result is given some input/data?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes I mean the first part, ordering the products returned when accessing the ManyToManyField on each Collection in the queryset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to optimise DB queries by fetching all related objects in a single query, if you add [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) objects to this you can change the queryset used to prefetch including the ordering

```
qs = Collection.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.order_by('launch_date'))
)
```

You could also just add default ordering to the model if this ordering is always desired

```
class Product(models.Model):

    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['launch_date']
```